# Django - Empty admin form of Model

Tags: python, django

I have one model "Inventario" like this:

```
class Inventario(models.Model):
    producto = models.ForeignKey(Producto)
    cantidad = models.DecimalField(default=0, decimal_places=2, max_digits=10)
    ubicacion = models.ForeignKey(Ubicacion, null=True, blank=True, related_name='en_inventario')
    epc = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    serial = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    fecha = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s (%s)' % (self.producto.item, self.epc)
```

and registered in the admin.py like this:

```
from almacen.models import Inventario
admin.site.register(Inventario)
```

The List of Entries are shown in the Admin

[image]

But inside the details of one of that entries, nothing appears
[image]

Even if I try to save and continue, an error is thrown
[image]

What is happening? This error is affecting only this Model

Comment: What version of Django are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably can't use the default admin.py. Turn on DEBUG and try something like this:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from almacen.models import Inventario

class InventarioAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ['producto', 'fecha', 'ubicacion']

admin.site.register(Inventario, InventarioAdmin)
```

I suspect that something (the ForeignKey? the auto_now_add field?) isn't being well-handled by the default Admin. Try shrinking the number of fields available.

See also the [ModelAdmin docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-objects)

Comment: You were right, one of the Foreign Key fields were doing a mess, I had an error in the __unicode__ of one of the ForeignKeyFields, the strange thing is that the DEBUG doesn't show anything. Thnks